# De una cadena de texto, encontrar las palabras y cuantas veces se repiten

Tags: c++, array

Ejemplo:

```
la palabra fe es monosílaba,así como la palabra sol
```

- así  1
- como 1
- es 1
- fe 1
- la 2
- monosílaba 1
- palabra 2
- sol 1

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Aquí no se le hacen los deberes a nadie... se responden dudas  y preguntas. Te sugiero pasarte por el [tour] para entender cómo funciona este portal y, de paso, ganarás tu primera medalla. También te convendría revisar [ask] para aprender a elaborar buenas preguntas. Las preguntas bien elaboradas suelen tener más y mejores respuestas

Comment: Hola, aqui no hacemos tareas, pero si te puedo dar una pista de que camino tomar. Pon en google `std::map` y `std::stringstream`. Con esas herramientas en mano vas a llegar a la solucion rapido

Answer (score 0):

Realmente lo que pides es fácilmente solucionable haces una función que cuente las palabras esto se puede hacer si cuentas los espacios en blanco, usas esto para un for que llegue hasta dicho numero y copie los caracteres del string desde la posición en la que empieza la palabra hasta la posición en la que termina en otro string luego compara los string donde se hayan copiado las palabras declara una variable 2d en el cual la segunda de las dimensiones sea el numero de palabras y la primera de las dimensiones sea 2 y ahi guardas la posicion de la palabra y el numero de veces que se repite en cuestión luego muestras por pantalla las palabras en orden y con el numero de veces que se repite al lado.